# Enqueue script, taking no effect

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I've added my `custom_script.js` to my child theme by making a `/js` folder, and I added it within my `functions.php` like this:

```
/*** Make Header Shrink on Page Scroll**/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scroll_enqueue_script', 15 );
function scroll_enqueue_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'scroll_custom_script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '4.3.1', 
        true 
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll_custom_script' );
}
```

I see the script through the developer console in my elements, and in my resources I can see the code, but it doesn't seem to trigger. I made an alert on scroll to test if it would fire, but I can't seem to get it to trigger.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(function(){
        var hasBeenTrigged = false;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            // if scroll is greater/equal than 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !hasBeenTrigged) { 
                alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
                hasBeenTrigged = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is really a Javascript issue than a WordPress one which is better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set the alert if you've scrolled 100px from the top of the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var ScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());

        if (ScrollTop > 100) {
            alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a JSFiddle showing it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/steckinsights/vfgos4o3/1/embedded/result/)

Assuming you want to do more than just show an alert, here would be how you add a class of "scroll" to an element with the class of "site-header" and have it removed when you are less than 100px from the top of the browser window:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var ScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());

        if (ScrollTop > 100) {
            $( ".site-header" ).addClass( "scroll" );
        }else{
            $( ".site-header" ).removeClass( "scroll" );
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: @MeirSnyder, this is long overdue, but -- if this helped, mind voting up?